# Losing data (and adding random nodes) when using a function to create items for linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers, memory, linked-list

I have a linked list in C. I want to fill it up dynamically based on a 'stock level'. For testing purposes, I have created a small program. The stock level here is simply hard coded at 1, but it is enough to demonstrate.

In this code, the first node in the linked list is special, so I create it myself and it always stays the same. The rest of the nodes (the number of which match the 'stock level') are created dynamically.

I know the problem has something to do with scope, but I'm really not sure how.

If I set the 'stock level' to 0, everything works fine. The output looks like this:

```
 inside function: (5, 10)
outside function: (5, 10)
```

If I increase the 'stock level' to 1, the output looks like this:

```
 inside function: (5, 10)  ; Correct
 inside function: (2, 3)   ; Correct
outside function: (5, 10)  ; Still Correct
outside function: (24, 48) ; What..?
outside function: (0, 1)
outside function: (1848777136, 32767)
```

I tried to `malloc` the head of the linked list, but I got similar results. I've also tried to `malloc` the `.next` part of each struct, again with similar results. I've been trying to fix this for a while and ended up just doing an inline for loop to handle this, but I really would like for it to be in a seperate function (as I keep having to repeat that specific bit of code a couple of places).

Thanks for any help.

For reference, here is the code I am using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                       

struct Item {
  int x;
  int y;
  struct Item *next;
};  

void create(struct Item *start, int stock) {
  *start = (struct Item){ .x = 5, .y = 10, .next = NULL };

  int i;
  struct Item *previous = start;
  for (i = 1; i <= stock; i++ ) { 
    previous->next = &(struct Item){ .x = (i*2), .y = (i*3), .next = NULL };
    previous = previous->next;
  }   

  struct Item *node = start;
  while (node != NULL) {
    printf(" inside function: (%d, %d)\n", node->x, node->y);
    node = node->next;
  }   
}   

int main() {
  struct Item head;
  int stock = 1;

  create(&head, stock);

  struct Item *node = &head;
  while (node != NULL) {
    printf("outside function: (%d, %d)\n", node->x, node->y);
    node = node->next;
  }   

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
previous->next = &(struct Item){ .x = (i*2), .y = (i*3), .next = NULL };
```

stores the address of a local stack variable that goes out of scope when you exit the `for` loop.  After this, accessing the memory results in undefined behaviour.  One likely problem is that other parts of your program will write to the same stack locations.

You can fix this by dynamically allocating memory for your list elements

```
previous->next = malloc(sizeof(*previous->next));
if (previous->next == NULL) {
    /* handle out of memory */
}
*previous->next = (struct Item){ .x = (i*2), .y = (i*3), .next = NULL };
```

If you do this, note that you need to call `free` to later return this memory to the system.

Comment: I believe it should be `previous->next = (struct Item*)malloc(sizeof(struct Item));`

Comment: Both of those work (thanks!), but what is the different between the two if there is one?

Comment: @ScottyBauer You [shouldn't cast the return from malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) in C.  (You do need to in C++ however.)  I prefer `sizeof(*previous->next)` as it'll keep working even if you later change the type of `previous->next`

Comment: @Grashlok As you say, both will work.  Unsurprisingly, I prefer my version :).  See my previous comment to Scotty Bauer for the reasons.

Comment: @simonc looking at this code again, isn't this invoking undefined behavior? Specifically, the `malloc(sizeof(*previous->next))` we're de-referencing a dangling pointer, we're trying to set `previous->next` to point to a valid range of memory but doing so by de-referencing it to get the size? Does `sizeof()` do something I am unaware of? Let me know I'm very curious now!!

Comment: @ScottyBauer `sizeof(*previous->next)` will be evaluated at compile time.  It considers the type of the argument but doesn't dereference it.  It is equivalent to your `sizeof(struct Item)` but has the added (small) benefit of not risking getting out of date if the type of `previous->next` is later changed.